# Using String.format() when a string length varies

Tags: java, string, format

How do I use `String.format()` when the length of the `String` is unpredictable? I'm making a program that requires an email and the place where the "@" will vary depending on the length on what comes before it.

Edit: What I mean is, I need to check if the email format is valid. Example: johndoe@johndoe.usa is a valid email, but doing johndoejohndoe,usa isn't valid. So I need to figure out if

1. the format is valid
2. finding out how to see if the format is valid with `String.format()` when the `String` length will vary depending on the email.

Comment: Please include some examples (emails that you would like to format) and the expected results?

Comment: A bit of a workaround would be to parse the string and manually look for the '@' delimiter. This can be done with a for-loop that traverses over each character.

Comment: String.format (..) does not use a `@` token but uses special format specifiers such a `%s` for a string or `%d` for a number. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax . It does not matter where these values appear in the String. They will be inserted in the place of the corresponding specifier.

Comment: @Gosu edited, read OP.

Comment: @redge Well how will I find out if the format of a specified `String` such as "johndoe@johndoe.usa" is a valid format. I mean we need to check if there is an @ symbol and if there is a . somewhere following it.

Comment: Ah! this is not String.format() String.format is for creating a formatted string not checking that the format is correct. I suggest that you work out what your rules are and manually check they are satisfied using other String methods like string.indexOf("@") and string.indexOf(".")

Comment: @AlexTrevoso Hi, I have provided a possible solution to your problem using [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), please take a look! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what you would deem as a valid email, but I did the following based on this assumption:

> A valid email is a string that has at least 1 word character,
>   followed by the '@' sign, followed by at least 1
>   alphabet, followed by the '.' character, and ending with
>   at least 1 alphabet

**Here's the code using regex:**

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class QuickTester {

    private static String[] emails = {"abc@gmail.com",
            "randomStringThatMakesNoSense",
            "abc@@@@@", "thisIsRegex@rubbish",
            "test123.com", "goodEmail@hotmail.com",
            "@asdasd@gg.com"};

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for(String email : emails) {
        System.out.printf("%s is %s.%n",
                email, 
                (isValidEmail(email) ? "Valid" : "Not Valid"));
        }   
    }

    // Assumes that domain name does not contain digits
    private static boolean isValidEmail (String emailStr) {

        // Looking for a string that has at least 1 word character,
        // followed by the '@' sign, followed by at least 1
        // alphabet, followed by the '.' character, and ending with
        // at least 1 alphabet
        String emailPattern = 
                "^\\w{1,}@[a-zA-Z]{1,}\\.[a-zA-Z]{1,}$";

        Matcher m = Pattern.compile(emailPattern).matcher(emailStr);
        return m.matches();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
abc@gmail.com is Valid.
randomStringThatMakesNoSense is Not Valid.
abc@@@@@ is Not Valid.
thisIsRegex@rubbish is Not Valid.
test123.com is Not Valid.
goodEmail@hotmail.com is Valid.
@asdasd@gg.com is Not Valid.
```

Based on your definition of a valid email, you could adjust the [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) accordingly. I hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean, thanks! Sorry, I can word things very complicatedly.